# Issues with optional types and UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm going through O'Reilly's Swift Development with Cocoa and am getting the following error:

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

Against the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view) {
        // creating and adding a gravity behaviour
        let gravityBehaviour = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.imageView])
        dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(gravityBehaviour)

        // creating and adding a collision behaviour
        let collisionBehaviour = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.imageView])
        collisionBehaviour.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

        dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(collisionBehaviour)

        self.dynamicAnimator = dynamicAnimator
    }

}
}
```

The error is for this line:

```
if let dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view) {
```

When I add a question mark to dynamicAnimator to make it optional, I get new errors:

```
Expected '{' after 'if' condition
Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
Braced block of statements is an unusual closure
```

I'm reading up right now on optional types to try and understand them, but this is the code directly from the book. I've checked their forums and errata sections and no one has mentioned this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIDynamicAnimator` initializers aren't failable, like they are for some classes, so you aren't getting back an optional value in that line. Without an optional value, the `if let...` construction doesn't make sense, so the compiler doesn't let you write that. Just get rid of the `if` part and you'll be fine.

```
let dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
// no braces, either
// ...
```